# How do I use spring property sources within a child annotation context?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, annotations

I'm trying to replicate something that works with XML config using annotated configuration classes. The problem I'm hitting is that property sources defined in the child context are not accessible.

The xml that works looks like

**Parent context :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="proxyChannelQueue" class="java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="10"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Child Context :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="proxy-host.properties"/>

    <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server"
          p:handler-ref="proxyHostHandler"
            init-method="start">
        <constructor-arg value="${proxyHostPort}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="proxyHostHandler" class="com.sjl.web.ProxyHostHandler"
            p:proxyChannelQueue-ref="proxyChannelQueue"/>
</beans>
```

**Start up code :**

```
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext parentContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test/parent-context.xml");
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext childContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"test/child-context.xml"}, parentContext);
```

My attempt at doing this using configuration classes looks like.

**Parent Context :**

```
@Configuration
public class ParentConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "proxyChannelQueue")
    public BlockingQueue<ProxyChannel> getProxyChannelQueue() {
        return new ArrayBlockingQueue<ProxyChannel>(10);
    }
}
```

**Child Context :**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:proxy-host.properties")
public class ChildContext {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChildContext.class);
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Resource(name = "proxyChannelQueue")
    private BlockingQueue<ProxyChannel> proxyChannelQueue;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HierarchicalAnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ChildContext.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Server getJettyServer() throws Exception {
        int proxyHostPort = environment.getProperty("proxyHostPort", Integer.class);
        Server server = new Server(proxyHostPort);
        server.setHandler(getHandler());
        server.start();

        return server;
    }

    @Bean
    public Handler getHandler() {
        ProxyHostHandler proxyHostHandler = new ProxyHostHandler();
        proxyHostHandler.setProxyChannelQueue(proxyChannelQueue);
        return proxyHostHandler;
    }
}
```

**Start up code :**

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext parentContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ParentConfiguration.class);
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext childContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
childContext.setParent(parentContext);
childContext.register(ChildContext.class);
childContext.refresh();
```

I'm getting a null pointer while trying to retrieve the proxyHostPort within the ChildContext getJettyServer method. Inspecting the environment variable shows that it contains only 2 property sources (systemProperties and systemEnvironment) and not the 3 I expect.

The same configuration works if I run them as a single combined context. E.g. :

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext parentContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ParentConfiguration.class, ChildContext.class);
```

However I want the isolation that using parent contexts provide.

Cheers,
Peter

Comment: which version of spring is used?

Comment: I'm using 3.1.2.RELEASE. For kicks I tried upgrading to 3.2.1.RELEASE. It has the same behavior.

Comment: I tried the same in a project and it worked for me, Can you enable trace level logging for spring

Comment: Well that is weird. Here's the logs : http://pastebin.com/7945M6tu

Comment: I've copied my test project to git-hub, can you try it https://github.com/arunpjohny/SO-15015053

Comment: I'm now very puzzled. Your project works, but why does it not ask for a CGLIB? I get CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes when using your dependencies...

Comment: Can you create a trimmed down version of your project in github so that i can have a complete view, no need of jetty or anything, something like what I shared

Comment: Hi, it turns out this was an issue in the project setup, not the code. I copied the project from someone using eclipse and this resulted in the 3.1 spring libraries being glued to the classpath in IntelliJ. I wiped out the .eclipse file and reimported the project and everything works. I believe the environment injection works for 3.2 but not 3.1. I also notice that cglib is not a requirement for 3.2 (it was for 3.1). You were very helpful with all this, if you wack something in an answer I will accept it.